# Space-efficient data structure for partial products of a sequence?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, space-complexity

I need to suggest a data structure with memory complexity of `O(n)` that do the following actions:

1. `Init()` – initialize an empty data structure.
2. `Insert (I,x)` -  insert to the I th place the number x. the numbers that were before in I places and after will be one index higher. Complexity:`O(logn)`.
3. `Get(i)` – return the i element. Complexity: `O(logn)`.
4. `multiplyAllBut(down,up)`- return the multiply numbers without the numbers that appear between the down and up places. Complexity: `O(logn)`.

I thought about AVL tree but I have problems with changeing the indexs. Also, skip-list but it not at the requierd complexity.

Thanks. :)

Comment: "return the multiply numbers without the numbers that appear between the down and up places." What does that mean can you elaborate?

Comment: a1*a2*a3*a up *a down ***an .. everything that between a up and a down wont be in the multiply. @poorvank_bhatia

Comment: It's not possible to achieve #4 as you need to do (n-2) multiplications in the worst case scenario (`multiplyAllBut(min(numbers), max(numbers)`)

Comment: @Sklivvz I believe this is possible if you precompute partial products.  Check my answer for details.

Comment: @templatetypedef ah, yes, that's smart

Answer (score 2):

Except for the very last operation (multiplying everything by a value), you can implement this using an [order statistic tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree), an augmented BST where each node stores the number of elements to the left and right. I believe that starting with this data structure and adding in a bit more information, you can get all four operations working efficiently.

The basic idea is the following: augment each node in the tree to store the product of all the numbers in the left subtree and the product of all the numbers stored in the right subtree. We'll call these `leftProd` and `rightProd`. These values can be computed in time O(1) from the values in a node's left and right subtrees and the value in the node itself, so augmenting the tree with this extra information doesn't change the asymptotic time complexity of the implementation. Additionally, store two more values: `minIndex` and `maxIndex`, the minimum and maximum indices in the subtree rooted at a given node. These two can be computed efficiently from the values in the left and right subtrees, so there's no cost associated with adding in this extra augmentation.

Now, suppose you want to look up the product of the values in the range [low, high]. To do so, recursively search the tree as follows:

1. If [low, high] is purely to the left of the index of the current node, recursively compute the value in the left subtree.
2. If [low, high] is purely to the right of the index of the current node, recursively compute the value in the right subtree.
3. If [low, high] exactly matches the range `[minIndex, maxIndex]`, return the product of the node's vaule, `leftProd`, and `rightProd`.
4. Otherwise, make a recursive call in the left subtree for [low, index - 1], a recursive call in the right subtree for [index + 1, high], and return the product of those two numbers and the node's own value.

We need to justify why this will work efficiently. The crux of the idea is the following. Cases 1 and 2 make exactly one recursive call. Case 3 makes no recursive calls. Case 4 will make two recursive calls. Each case does O(1) work each. If not for the branching done in Case 4, the recursion would just walk down the tree from the top to the bottom, doing O(1) work per level, so the total work done is O(log n).

However, I'm going to claim that Case 4 doesn't actually branch as much as you might think. Imagine the very first time in the recursion that Case 4 happens. When it does, it will make two recursive calls, one to the left and one to the right. Notice that those recursive calls are for very specific subranges: the call on the left subtree asks for a range from some index up to the last index in the left subtree, and the call on the right subtree asks for a range from the first index in the right subtree up to some index. In other words, the recursive calls made are on subranges that are "flush up" against one side of the subtrees they recur into.

Now, think about any time that we encounter Case 4 from that point forward. Whenever we do, we know that one of the two ranges that the recursion will descend into will consist of the range of a full subtree. That will immediately result in us hitting Case 3, so that recursive call effectively isn't a real recursive call. This means that the number of times that Case 4 can "truly" branch is at most once. From that point forward, the recursion effectively continues down just one path in the tree.

Overall, this means that we can bound the total work done - at least asymptotically - as the work needed to walk from the top of the tree down to the bottom twice, doing O(1) work per node. This works out to O(log n) total work, as required.

And how much space do we need? This augmentation uses only O(1) space per node, so the total space needed is O(n).

Hope this helps!

Comment: You don't need to store two products in each node. Just store the product of each subtree in its root. Then look at the children to get what you need.  It's _exactly_ the same as the order statistic tree, substituting multiplication for addition.